# Is the integral of a distribution function on a measure zero set is always zero?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

As is well known, the Lebesgue integral of a Lebesgue integrable function on a Lebesgue measure zero set is always zero.

Question: Is the **integral of a distribution function**(distribution means here the notion in Sobolev space theory or PDE, such as the  $L^1$ or  $L^2$ or  $L^1_{locally}$ functions on domains of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or some kind of manifolds  ) **on a measure zero set is always zero?**

Remark 1  I don't know whether this integral can be called the Lebesgue integral.

Remark2  **Are there some kind of measures that the integra value on measure 0 set is not 0**?

Comment: What do you mean by a (probability?) distribution function on a set of measure zero?  A probability function would be a set of discrete points.

Comment: @herbsteinberg  Sorry, distribution refers here the notion in PDE. I  have add explanations.

Comment: Sorry - I know almost nothing about PDE or Sobelev.  The closest I can think of is Schwartz distribution idea, where the distribution is in terms of delta functions.